# JHipster Entity doesn't be created in JAVA(Spring Framework)

Tags: jhipster

I am trying to create new entities with JHipster in Java(Spring Framework)
When I try to relate my entity with existing User entity (which comes from JHipster by default) I got some errors.

Here is my entities:

[image: [1]]

I got this errors:
[image: [2]]

Comment: Please do not make post where most of the content is external links. Those links will eventually expire leaving your post with little to no value for users experiencing similar problems.

Comment: Please don't use images (they are unreadable), paste plain text if you want people to try to reproduce your problem!.Also give details like JHipster version or output of jhipster info

Answer (score 3):

You can't create a bi-directional many-to-many relationship between Course and User, it's not supported please read the [documentation](https://jhipster.github.io/managing-relationships/#available-relationships). You should also reconsider your object model, it seems to me that there should be Student and Instructor entities which should have a one-to-one relationship with User.

After you gave access to your git repo, I discovered that you are using microservices architecture, it would have helped to say it immediately. What you are trying to do cannot work because User is an entity that exists only in Gateway while your other entities exist only in service app.

Bottom line is: either you don't create relationships with User and only add a userId string field to your entities, or you switch to a monolith application which is much simpler to understand.

Comment: Thank you Gaël. I thought student and instructor are user groups(like: ROLE_USER, ROLE_INSTRUCTOR). Do i still need to create student and instructor entities? If i need, how can I derive the student-insturctor class from the user class(comes from jhipster by default)?

Comment: Unless you are building a simplistic app, roles will not allow you to manage differences between Student and Instructor. These 2 entities are part of your domain, so they should be materialized, otherwise you're not doing OOP. I did not suggest that you derive student from user, I just suggested that you create a one-to-one relationship with User. Think about separation of concerns principle, User is made for authentication and authorization.

Comment: Thank you Gael. I redesign my entities as you told. This time; application works but i still have smillar errors on terminal(I guess its about my one-to-one relationships with User). Here is my entities and errors: http://imgur.com/a/kW8p9

Comment: Please don't use images and share your git repo, I don't use jDL often myself, I use the yeoman entity generator which is question based, so it's easier for me to review your whole config.

Comment: I create my entities with entity generator and i still have same errors. Here is my git repo: https://github.com/canberkizgi/mucs .

Comment: You should have said earlier that you were using microservices